# from list of dictionaries make a dict such that the same value in the dictionaries will become the key and the values are the items which are left

Tags: python, dictionary

In the given dictionary we have `label`, `parent_label` and `url` as the keys. Same `parent_label` should contain the `[label,url]`. If the `parent_label` is duplicated then the `[label, url]` of that particular `parent_label` should be appended.

The input is

```
top = [{u'label': u'Square HSS Tool Bits',
        u'parent_label': u'Lathe Tools',
        u'url': u'/hss-tools/hss-square-tool-bits'},
        {u'label': u'HSS Tapped Punches',
        u'parent_label': u'Press Tools',
        u'url': u'/hss-tapped-punches'},
       {u'label': u'Carbide Radius End Mills',
       u'parent_label': u'Milling Tools',
       u'url': u'/carbide-radius-end-mills'},
       {u'label': u'HSS Mini Straight Punches',
       u'parent_label': u'Press Tools',
       u'url': u'/hss-mini-straight-punches'},
       {u'label': u'Carbide Square Tool Bits',
       u'parent_label': u'Lathe Tools',
       u'url': u'/carbide-square-tool-bits'},
       {u'label': u'HSS Center Drill Bits',
       u'parent_label': u'Drilling Tools',
       u'url': u'/hss-tools/hss-center-drill'},
       {u'label': u'Rectangular HSS Tool Bits',
        u'parent_label': u'Lathe Tools',
        u'url': u'/rectangular-hss-tool-bits'},
        {u'label': u'News', u'parent_label': u'About Us', u'url': 
        u'/news'}]
```

The output should look like,

```
{'Lathe Tools' : [[u'Square HSS Tool Bits',u'/hss-tools/hss-square- 
    tool-bits'],[u'Rectangular HSS Tool Bits',u'/rectangular-hss-tool-bits']],
'Press Tools':[['HSS Tapped Punches',u'/hss-tapped-punches'],[u'HSS Mini Straight Punches',u'/hss-mini-straight-punches'],....]
```

I've tried like :

```
for i in top:
    if i['parent_label'] in k.keys():
        k[i['parent_label']] = [[i['label'],i['url']]]
```

my o/p is :

```
 {u'About Us': [[u'News', u'/news']],
 u'Drilling Tools': [[u'HSS Center Drill Bits',
 u'/hss-tools/hss-center-drill']],
 u'Lathe Tools': [[u'Rectangular HSS Tool Bits',
  u'/rectangular-hss-tool-bits']],
 u'Milling Tools': [[u'Carbide Radius End Mills',
 u'/carbide-radius-end-mills']],
 u'Press Tools': [[u'HSS Mini Straight Punches',
  u'/hss-mini-straight-punches']]}
```

Please help me out guys. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a job for `defaultdict`:
It acts like a dictionary but instead of raising an error if you access an element that was never set, it sets it to an instance of the chosen default object (here a `list`) on the first access.

The issue in your case is that you override the content associated with the key in your final `dict` when you want to add an element.
You are probably looking for something like that:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for d in top:
    result[d[u'parent_label']].append([d[u'label'], d[u'url']])
print(result)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'About Us': [['News', '/news']],
             'Drilling Tools': [['HSS Center Drill Bits',
               '/hss-tools/hss-center-drill']],
             'Lathe Tools': [['Square HSS Tool Bits',
               '/hss-tools/hss-square-tool-bits'],
              ['Carbide Square Tool Bits', '/carbide-square-tool-bits'],
              ['Rectangular HSS Tool Bits', '/rectangular-hss-tool-bits']],
             'Milling Tools': [['Carbide Radius End Mills',
               '/carbide-radius-end-mills']],
             'Press Tools': [['HSS Tapped Punches', '/hss-tapped-punches'],
              ['HSS Mini Straight Punches', '/hss-mini-straight-punches']]})
```